# Adding multiple instances of a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, class

I have a simple `Person` class and a `Club` class that should contain lots of `Person` instances:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    persons = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How do I add more than one `Person` to the `persons` attribute? I want to build a database and then save it as follows:

```
club = Club(name='some_club')
club.person.add(Person(name='Alex'))
club.person.add(Person(name='John'))
club.save()
# etc. ...
```

Comment: Can a person be in more than one club?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key is the wrong way round. To allow multiple people to be members of each club, the FK needs to be on Person pointing to Club.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    club = models.ForeignKey("Club", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

...

some_club = Club(name='some_club')
some_club.save()

some_club.person_set.add(Person(name='Alex'))
some_club.person_set.add(Person(name='John'))
# Or:
Person.objects.create(name="Alex", club=some_club)
```

Comment: If you use a ManyToManyField, can't it be either way?

Comment: Yes but is that what the op wants? Can a person be a member of more than one club?

Comment: It seems like it would be a strange restriction, unless this is a really artificial exercise.

Comment: @Barmer No, a `Person` should be only in one club.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

club1 = Club(name='some_club')
club1.save()

person1 = Person(name='Alex', club=club1)
person1.save()
person2 = Person(name='John', club=club1)
person2.save()
```

Edit: changed istance name to `club1`

Comment: This only allows a person to be in one club.

Comment: @ipaleka Thanks ... when you write `club=club` is this the entity name with lower case? So if I had `class ClubX(...)` would it be `clubx=club` or `club_x=club`?

Comment: @alex_lewis When you write `x = y` there, the first one is the field in the class, the second is the variable you're assigning to the field. It's a coincidence that these are all the same and also the same as the class name with different case.

Comment: @alex_lewis If you write `club_foo = Club(name='foo')`, you would then write `Person(name='Alex', club=club_foo)`

Comment: @Barmar Great. thanks. To clarify what I mean: if the class was instead called `ClubWonderful`, then `club_foo = ClubWonderful(name='foo')`, what would the keyword be in the `Person` instance? i.e. `Person(name='Alex', clubwonderful=club_foo)` or `Person(name='Alex', club_wonderful=club_foo)`

Comment: The keyword is whatever name you gave that field inside the `Person` model. So `club = models.ForeignKey(...)` means the keyword is `club`.